# How can I remap Alt+Space to Alt+Shift in AutoHotkey?

Tags: autohotkey

I want to remap <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Space</kbd> to <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd> -- <kbd>Left Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Right Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Space</kbd> to <kbd>Left Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Left Shift</kbd>.

How can I do this in AutoHotkey?

Answer (score 1):

I don't have a good way to test this, but maybe something like:

```
!Space::!+
<!>!Space::<!<+
```

Comment: it does not work

Comment: What application are you using to test this?